# How To Add Files Automatically?

Tags: build-process, installshield, release-management, autorelease, software-packaging

I'm Using Install shield 2012 Basic MSI Project. We planned to make build automation, I found the solution to trigger install shield build pro-grammatically using "ISCMDBLD"

Challenges,

1. How to add files and folders into install shield destination folder pro grammatically.
2. How to compare the files from source location to install shield destination location before triggering build.
3. Changing package code(we can set release view right,if any other option let me know).

How to add file automatically ? is it possible or not.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Install Shield with its user interface, if you want to add files programmatically, you may need to write some scripts (batch, python or whatever script), and then call the public API exposed by Install shield to make the whole installer build process automatic.

Comment: I don't have example code in hand, but i find some useful links which contain examples and API references.

http://codecontext.blogspot.in/2012/04/installshield-automation-using-c.html

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm